# How to select Fruit object from Fruit ID (unique)

Tags: c#, linq, select

Is this the best way to select the Fruit object I need from the ID?

So I'm taking the ID and returning its name, id being unique, so there will only ever be one result.

If I don't use .Single() I get IQueryable but I just want the single object

```
var fruitName = (from p in fruitDB.Fruits
                               where p.FruitID == id
                               select p.FruitName).Single();
```

Comment: I'm unsure what the problem is. Your query should select the FruitName, as intended. If you want the `Fruit` itself just `select p` instead of `select p.FruitName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Single()` is fine - however if it doesn't have any results it will throw an exception.  If you want it to return `null` instead do `SingleOrDefault()`.  This will give you the only object that was returned, or if none were found, null.

If the result set will return more than 1 item (not likely with an ID), and you only want the first item, use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead

```
fruitDb.Fruits.SingleOrDefault(f => f.FruitId == id);
```